# How to make slideout animation on click of a screen?

Tags: android

I have designed a screen in which on click of a button slide in menu comes out from bottom and on click of other button the menu will slide out and disappear but my requirement is i want to make the menu slide out whenever i click anywhere in the screen outside the menu part. Please tell me how to achieve that.

```
//Code
if(v==mBtnMenu){
            mBtnMenu.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
            mFrameLayoutCustom.startAnimation(slideInAnim);
            mFrameLayoutCustom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }   else if (v == mBtnMenuonTop) {
            mBtnMenu.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
            mFrameLayoutCustom.startAnimation(slideOutAnim);
            mFrameLayoutCustom.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to use a

```
  YourItemName.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          

        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(!hasFocus)
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```